# How to configure auto completion on docker-compose alias

Tags: docker, alias, auto-completion

I installed docker-compose, set up auto completion which works as its supposed to. However it does not work on aliases.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bash just do:

Get the configuration from the official project:

```
sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/1.23.2/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose
```

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/)

Reset the terminal to be sure new configuration are load.

```
reset
```

**Update**

Once the file is installed as before, open it whit your favorite text editor go to the end of file and append your alias to this line:

```
complete -F _docker_compose docker-compose docker-compose.exe
```

so after the modification it will be:

```
complete -F _docker_compose docker-compose docker-compose.exe *yoralias*
```

**NOTE:** be careful with the alias you choose, you could use a name of existing command (I.E. dc exist as a command Read [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udc.htm))

Comment: I did this and it works but what I want is to work on an alias.
I set up an alias to use `dc` instead of  `docker-compose` to save some writing and when I use the alias auto completion stops working.

Comment: ok, i get it, I'll update my answer in a minut

Comment: @MirtHlaj does it work for you? I've got error: `my_alias bash: completion: function `_docker_compose' not found`.

Comment: And I should point out that my alias was `:d`. And using `:` wasn't the best of ideas. Simple `d` works fine.